# Plotting multiple maps with ggmap

Tags: r, maps, ggmap

I can plot a UK map with `ggmap` with a point like this:

```
library(ggmap)
UK_map <- get_map(location = c(-2.65, 53.7), zoom = 5, maptype = "hybrid")
UK_map <- ggmap(ggmap=UK_map, extent = "device", legend = "right")
UK_map + geom_point(data = data.frame(x = -1.81, y = 55.655), aes(x, y), size  = 5)
```

[image]

However, if I try to use [Winston Chang's `multiplot` function](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/), the point disappears.

```
multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, cols) {
    require(grid)

    # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
    plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

    numPlots = length(plots)

    # Make the panel
    plotCols = cols                          # Number of columns of plots
    plotRows = ceiling(numPlots/plotCols) # Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols

    # Set up the page
    grid.newpage()
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(plotRows, plotCols)))
    vplayout <- function(x, y)
        viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)

    # Make each plot, in the correct location
    for (i in 1:numPlots) {
        curRow = ceiling(i/plotCols)
        curCol = (i-1) %% plotCols + 1
        print(plots[[i]], vp = vplayout(curRow, curCol ))
    }

}

multiplot(UK_map, UK_map, cols = 2)
```

[image]

Why is the point disappearing and how can I get point to appear when using `multiplot`?

Answer (score 7):

The `multiplot` function doesn't know about the point, since you only pass it your `UK_map` object, which does not include the point. To have it plot the point, you would need to add the `geom_point` call to assignment of `UK_map`, like so:

```
UK_map_with_point <- UK_map + 
  geom_point(data = data.frame(x = -1.81, y = 55.655), aes(x, y), size  = 5)

multiplot(UK_map_with_point, UK_map, cols = 2)
```

[image: ggmap multiplot]

Or, alternatively, add the point on the fly within the call to `multiplot`:

```
multiplot(UK_map + geom_point(data = data.frame(x = -1.81, y = 55.655), 
                              aes(x, y), size  = 5), 
          UK_map + geom_point(data = data.frame(x = -2.81, y = 56.655), 
                              aes(x, y), size  = 5), cols = 2)
```

[image: ggmap multiplot2]

Comment: Whoops, I should really have spotted that.

Comment: ;) it's easy to make little mistakes like that.

Comment: The dangers of trying to do things in a rush…