# Multiple panned maps of various sections of the city with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, rgooglemaps

I can achive [Plotting multiple maps with ggmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599342/plotting-multiple-maps-with-ggmap) which is also possible with faceting as described in [Kale & Wickham (2013) *R Journal* paper](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf). But I would like to plot a multiple series of maps that *pan* around particular, zoomed areas of the city. This is sort of achievable if I look at the city coordinates obtained with `geocode()` function and roughly figure out what I need to subtract or add from longitude/latitude on each side of pan the view. Such solution is far from ideal. Let me illustrate with an example (note: `multiplot` function used from [Cookbook For R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/)).

```
library(ggmap)
library(RgoogleMaps)

#getting Bristol lat/long
BRS <- geocode("Bristol, UK")

#get the first (central) map from the coordinates
BristolMapCenter <- ggmap(get_map(c(lon=BRS$lon, lat=BRS$lat), zoom = 15))

#get the second map panned to the right by adding approx. 0.015 to longitude
BristolMapRight <- ggmap(get_map(c(lon=BRS$lon+0.015, lat=BRS$lat),zoom = 15))

#multiplot function
multiplot(BristolMapCenter, BristolMapRight, cols=2)
```

[image]

As you can see this is far from ideal as there is overall (I don't want overlap, I want "lined up continuation"), if not to say clunky, especially if I want to get a larger panning of the surrounding areas (lets say 9-12 maps), do it for multiple cities, plot some data on the top of it, and still have enough time in my life to grab a pint on the sun. So I wonder if there is any fast, sleek and automatic way to get those panned maps based on specific central coordinates?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal. You want multiple maps showing different areas of a city. Is the idea that the maps, if plotted directly adjacent would "line up" nicely? Or do you want some amount of overlap as in your example? Do you essentially want a big map that's cut up into little squares?

Comment: @Gregor I want multiple maps showing different areas of a city that "line up" without the overlap.

Comment: And, just to be clear, why not just use a single big map?

Comment: @Gregor Because I want to plot data on the top of those maps and I want to have a flexibility to adjust the level of zoom to create various versions of the "multiple mapped panning". So for instance, I would have one series of multiples with `zoom=10`, and another, more fine, with `zoom=15`.  I also want flexibility with the kind of data I want to add to each multiply - i.e. some data would be present only on the selected multiplies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your code:

```
library(ggmap)
library(RgoogleMaps)

#getting Bristol lat/long
BRS <- geocode("Bristol, UK")

#get the first (central) map from the coordinates
BristolMapCenter <- ggmap(get_map(c(lon=BRS$lon, lat=BRS$lat), zoom = 15))
```

we can extract the absolute ranges covered by the map at this zoom level:

```
z15width = sapply(BristolMapCenter$data, function(x) abs(diff(range(x))))
```

And then add multiples of this to your BRS coordinates.

```
BristolRight = ggmap(get_map(c(lon = BRS$lon + z15width["lon"],
                               lat = BRS$lat), zoom = 15))
```

These should line up nicely.

```
multiplot(BristolMapCenter, BristolRight, cols = 2)
```

[image]

You can move in any orthogonal direction by integer multiples of `z15width`, and things should continue to line up. And of course, you get a different width at a different zoom. You could write a script to calculate the width for many different zoom values and store that somewhere and reference it later.